# What is the quickest and simplest way of setting up a shared, remote git repo on Windows?

Tags: windows, git

I have just joined a team of two, and am in danger of having to being asked to use SourceSafe if I can't establish a git repo very quickly. I would like to avoid any web server etc. setup and just use a shared folder, but suggestions along this line haven't been very clear and have not worked.

First, I tried 'git init --bare' in the shared folder, and this seemed to work, but I cannot clone this repo to a local repo as I get told no repo exists there.

I would appreciate if somebody could give me clear instruction how to achieve this, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't cause any problem to share a repo this way, that's the exact setup we have here.

Be sure to specify slashes when giving repo location, and that the share has been accessed in the Explorer in case it requires authentication.

```
git clone //server/share/path/to/repo.git
```